# What is that "partial poweroff" feature?

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, bios, hardware-failure, powersave

Sometimes, when computer boots, I see motherboard logo, and sometimes, I don't. The situation depends on how computer was turned off.

I.e. operating system (software) can turn it of "partially", so that BIOS logo doesn't show.

Computer is not working in this mode, LEDs are off, coolers are off. It is not sleep or hibernate mode.

What is this mode? Or this is some hardware glitch?

**UPDATE**

Probably this is [UEFI boot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Booting).

**UPDATE 2**

Despite the fact that behavior looks like UEFI boot, I don't have the following option

[image]

Can it still be an UEFI boot?

Comment: Which OS? Also, are you talking about booting or shutting down? On one hand you mention seeing the MB manufacturer's logo during boot-up, and on the other hand you're talking about the computer being off. Are you saying the logo is visible on-screen but the computer is off?

Comment: MB logo is sometimes showing during boot and sometimes -- does not. Looks like in latter cases computer is not powered off totally. My question is what is this state. OS is Windows, but this doesn't matter since the state is maintained when power is off. I.e. motherboard remembers this state, not operating system.

Answer (score 0):

That state is most probably Hibernation and it informs the BIOS it will resume on next boot (or do a Warm Boot) and not a full startup, which is also known as a Cold Boot

Comment: Hybernation is disabled on my machine. Anyway, why hibernation would need to inform BIOS?

Comment: in some PCs it informs the BIOS so that it skips the OEM logo

Comment: How? How to control this?

Comment: in some windows configs, it's impossible to control, as windows reports different things each shutdown

Comment: How to control if it IS possible?

Comment: is fast startup enabled?